# HTTPRequestOperation within another operation

Tags: ios, iphone, afnetworking, nsoperation

I am trying to have afnetworking within an operation since i have few thread unsafe stuff which has to be done after the network connection is successful (core data functions). During this i am seeing there could be thread issue if i were to call the rest of my Operations methods from the completion block of HTTPRequestOperation. in this case is there a technique through which i can come out of the completion block at the same time all my other tasks run on my custom operation's thread.

Comment: Core data work with the response of a AFNetworking request: sounds like a job for Restkit?

Comment: yeah, but i prefer to use afnetworking and build it myself for core data

Comment: In that case, how about PerformSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

Comment: in that case will it execute on main thread or inside custom operations thread ?

Comment: Yup that's what it's for. It will deliver a message to the main thread for you.